# Compile java file in linux

Tags: java

I have added environment variables in /etc/profile and the compiled file has no package name. **Why `java Hello`  can not work and appear** *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.* I would like to know where is the problem, thanks.

[image: compile java file in linux]
Here is the code.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world on Linux.");
    }
}
```

---

> [Linux execute java command Error: Main class not found or loaded](https://blog.csdn.net/shepherd_dirk/article/details/90514982)
> java环境变量配置可参考
> [Java环境变量配置（CentOS）](https://www.cnblogs.com/ycyzharry/p/13934880.html)

[以上回答转自博客园提问](https://q.cnblogs.com/q/137984/) 谢谢 ycyzharry

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem, AFAICS, the second try yielded a proper output. So you should tell us, what problem you have.

Comment: I would like to know why ``` java HelloWorld``` occur **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld**. Because in my opinion it should works.

Comment: Because in your first command, you didn't set a classpath (as you did in your second command with the `-cp` option) and the current directory is not in your default classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run just `java HelloWorld` because in Linux, current directory "." is not in `$CLASSPATH`. (You can observe by running command `echo $CLASSPATH`)

Because of that, when you are specifying class path with `-cp .`; you are basically saying "When running that class, look for that class path."

Thus, you can run the command with second way.

For further information, you can check out [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My ```$CLASSPATH``` configuration is indeed wrong.